# Video streaming using coap protocol

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, video-streaming, iot

I am planning to use CoAP (constraint application protocol) for video streaming between two remote desktops which contains redhat Linux. I have installed respective package for CoAP from open source with .Json. But I am not finding any proper command to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no existing video streaming applications over CoAP. There is ongoing work by Tata Consultancy Services to implement this (drafted as [A-REaLiST](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhattacharyya-core-a-realist-02)), but that's early work with a very narrow scope (streaming over very unreliable connections like low power radio from a UAV).

CoAP is probably a suboptimal choice as a transport protocol between Linux desktop systems, you may want to look into RTSP or HTTP based methods instead.